# A backwards compatible solution for setCompoundDrawableTintList

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

[setCompoundDrawableTintList(ColorStateList tint)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawableTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) was added in API 23. What is the best way to achieve the same result on older API's?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but support library's `DrawableCompat` has a [setTintList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#setTintList(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)) method. I guess you may be able to use it in older APIs. I mean manually tint drawables by `DrawableCompat` and then assign to controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is one way. It has the drawback of manually iterating over the drawables though.